# "NetworkError: 404 Not Found" /style.ccs

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm getting an error in firebug:

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - (removed)/style.css"

What does that mean and what do I need to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTTP 404 means exactly what it says -- File Not Found.

Somewhere in your document, you are linking to (removed)/style.css, and that file doesn't exist (wrong name, wrong location) on the server. There is a line in your code probably like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="(removed)/style.css">
```

pointing to it, and that needs to be changed to point to wherever that file is actually located.

---

Update:

Change that line to `<link href="(removed)/wp-content/themes/imbalance2/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`

Comment: Updated my answer to show you how to fix it. Sorry, took me forever to get it formatted right. You will see the changes once you get it linked in the above form (assuming that theme is active in wordpress).

Answer (score 2):

If means that the css file you are trying to use does not exist at that location.

404 Not Found means exactly that, it couldn't find the file. If you click your link, you'll get an error page saying exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

A '404' simply tells you that the file you are looking for is not where you thought it would be. You must be using some content management system / framework which redirects '404' errors to that page, otherwise you see the standard browser page for that error.

What to do?
Correct the path, add the file in the right place

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress CSS files usually don't reside in the root directory - they're in the theme's folder

Here is yours - (removed)/wp-content/themes/imbalance2/style.css

Comment: Yes, you should. That means now the CSS file attached and all the styles in it being applied to your HTML code.

Comment: +1 because you contributed by digging up the correct CSS link. Cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

As said by others a 404 error means the file was not found.

Sometimes this may be tricky. For instance I just moved files to a new server (CF11) from an old one (CF7) and my .css files wouldn't load: I was getting 404 errors. How could this be? I transferred over my entire directory and all the other files were being displayed.

The answer was that I needed absolute paths as opposed to relative paths. Sometimes you see an error and go WTF but retracing your steps and your assumptions will most often solve the problem.