# Noscript issue in Django

Tags: html, css, django

I have a template with following line:

```
<link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

However when I inspect element in Chrome I find 2 errors

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/mysiteapp/css/style.css 404 (NOT FOUND) 
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/mysiteapp/css/style-desktop.css 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

This relates to some issue I am experiencing with formatting. Only place where `style-desktop.css` gets referenced in `html` code is:

```
<noscript>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/skel-noscript.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style-desktop.css' %}"/>
</noscript>
```

I inspected my `static`  folder and it contains the folder, with all listed items. Yet clearly it doesnt see it. I also added the `css` folder into `mysiteapp` directory, still no luck

There is a very similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043290/networkerror-404-not-found-style-ccs). But it didnt solve my issues

### Edit 1

Other `GET` requests are fine ex:

```
style.css (static/css) type="text/css"
```

But under it there is another one which gets 404:

```
style.css (mysiteapp/css) type="text/html"
```

I adjusted, but still no luck

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" type="text/css"/>`

Why it points to mysiteapp, is beyond me at this point. All static items are pointing to static folder

### Edit 2

Initiator of the css file is a js file, which is initiated by:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/skel.min.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: `DEBUG = True`? Otherwise, do you have any webserver configure to serves static files from `127.0.0.1:8000/mysiteapp/`?

Comment: Debug is on True, and not sure what you mean by the rest of that, rephrase please. My other static files and codes load just fine!

Comment: is there anything in your `urls.py` related to serving static files? Post that here. Also post variables from `settings.py` related to static files

Comment: nothing in any `urls.py` files about statics, and I did dynamic path `TEMPLATE_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH, 'templates')`
`TEMPLATE_DIRS = (TEMPLATE_PATH,)`STATIC_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_PATH,'static')`
`STATIC_URL = '/static/'`
`STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    STATIC_PATH,
)`

Comment: Could you edit your post to include the other GET requests that are working correctly?

Answer (score 1):

They are 404 because you are not yet serving static files via Django

This code was copied from the Django doc on [Serving static files during development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development). There is more information there.

```
#urls.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

The above needs to be included in your `urls.py` so that Django's url routing knows you are serving static files at `STATIC_URL` with the folder `STATIC_ROOT`.

STATIC_URL is the prefix for your static files. Typical default is `/static/`.

STATIC_ROOT will be the path to that folder on your computer.

When you move this project into production you are going to want to look into having a web server serve these files instead of Django.

Comment: I added all those items. But here is the problem, main style.css works. It is the noscript tag that causes problem and those two scripts dont get accessed. My other static files work fine, all pictures and codes work fine.  It is the series of 3 lines that I posted causes an issue

Comment: In your list of errors above `style.css` was 404 as well. is your "main style.css" a different one? The <noscript> tag will have no affect on those documents throwing a 404. Can you view these static files directly by putting http://127.0.0.1:8000/mysiteapp/css/style.css in your browser instead of your app? What is the url of the main style.css that is working?

Comment: Note how I wrote 2 different scripts, html that was given to me adjusts for different platforms and etc. So main part in the header loads the `css` file. And it partially works because majority of the things get loaded. However there are links to few more css files in `noscript` tag, THAT is where 404 come from. And no, I cant see anything